# Angular Lazy Loading loading same route again

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

https://stackblitz.com/github/sandypm2020/BookStore

```html
<ul class="leftNav">
  <li>
    <a routerLink="/books">Books</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a routerLink="/users">Users</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'books',
    loadChildren: () => import('./book/book.module').then((m) => m.BookModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then((m) => m.UserModule),
  },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'books' },
];
```

Guys I want to use lazy loading I have following routes and `URLs`. But for some reason when I go to `user` it loads `books` route again can someone help why that is happening?

Comment: You need to use routerLink instead of href in the anchor tags

Comment: Hi @Clashsoft I tried that but is not helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: change `href` to `routerLink` like the following :

```
<ul class="leftNav">
        <li>
          <a routerLink="/books">Books</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="/users">Users</a>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

Then go to `UserModule` and add the routes to import section like the following :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [UserListComponent, AddUserComponent, UserEditComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Comment: Hi @AbolfazlR I tried your suggestion but that's not helping

Answer (score 0):

I saw stackblitz, No need to import booklist component and user component in app.routing.module.ts, please remove and test again, let me know as well

Comment: Actually above answer fixed it I was missing router import for user module

Comment: Good, also you can consider above answer as Note then.